# How to have x axis labels every week from the last day going backwards?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot

```
dt.ls <- structure(list(Day = 1:24, Count = c(91, 72, 105, 85, 55, 63, 
59, 79, 62, 67, 54, 29, 9, 49, 82, 53, 53, 34, 45, 27, 114, 42, 
62, 75)), .Names = c("Day", "Count"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(dt.ls, aes(x = Day, y = Count)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

I would like to have axis labels on the last day (24th) and also on every other week before that (so 17th, 10th, 3rd), and it should work where the day axis spans over a month, such as with:

```
dt.ls <- structure(list(Day = c("2021-05-15", "2021-05-16", "2021-05-17", 
"2021-05-18", "2021-05-19", "2021-05-20", "2021-05-21", "2021-05-22", 
"2021-05-23", "2021-05-24", "2021-05-25", "2021-05-26", "2021-05-27", 
"2021-05-28", "2021-05-29", "2021-05-30", "2021-05-31", "2021-06-01", 
"2021-06-02", "2021-06-03", "2021-06-04", "2021-06-05", "2021-06-06", 
"2021-06-07", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-11", 
"2021-06-12", "2021-06-13", "2021-06-14", "2021-06-15", "2021-06-16", 
"2021-06-17", "2021-06-18", "2021-06-19", "2021-06-20", "2021-06-21", 
"2021-06-22"), Count = c(88, 83, 118, 116, 112, 90, 95, 55, 74, 
104, 77, 70, 82, 90, 104, 60, 90, 94, 75, 108, 88, 58, 66, 62, 
82, 65, 70, 57, 32, 12, 52, 85, 56, 56, 37, 48, 30, 117, 45)), .Names = c("Day", 
"Count"), row.names = c(NA, -39L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(dt.ls, aes(x = Day, y = Count)) + geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Here we should have labels for 22 June, 15 June, 8 June, 1 June, 25 May and 18 May

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is a little awkward, but bear with me...

We use `seq.Date` to generate dates every seven days. The small issue is that we can only create a date sequence from the first (earliest) date, not the last date (as is required in this case). I bet lubridate has a good function for this, but in base R we can still get this done.

Basically we create `date_offset`, which is the remainder of the total number of days in the plot divided by seven. We then use that offset (in this case, 3 days) to add to the minimum date in our `seq.Date` call; that shifts the first date from 15 to 18 May. From there it's pretty straightforward, we just use the `breaks` argument in `scale_x_date`.

```
date_offset <- as.integer((max(as.Date(dt.ls$Day)) - min(as.Date(dt.ls$Day)))) %% 7
x_axis_breaks <- rev(
    seq.Date(
        from = (min(as.Date(dt.ls$Day)) + date_offset),
        to = max(as.Date(dt.ls$Day)),
        by = "week"
    )
)

dt.ls %>%
    mutate(Day = as.Date(Day)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Day, y = Count)) +
        geom_col() +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) +
        scale_x_date(breaks = x_axis_breaks)
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Thank you ! Although I get an error from the last line: `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`. Also, is there a way to make it work with both examples ?

Comment: Ah right, I had actually converted the `Day` variable to a date. Have updated the post to reflect that. You will be able to use the same strategy for integers rather than dates, you'll just need to use `seq` instead of `seq.Date`, and `scale_x_continuous` rather than `scale_x_date`.

Comment: Great, thank you (+1)  FYI there is a small typo on `mutate(Day = as.Date(Day)` (missing a closing parenthesis)